# Biometrics for a second UK partner visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, australian-citizens

I had a partner visa back in 2014 for the UK. We stayed there for 10 months and then returned back to Australia. We would like to move back to the UK, but I'm not sure if I need to do biometrics again. I would need to fly from my home in from Cairns to Brisbane for these biometric scans, and I don’t want to this unless I really need to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to provide biometrics again.

Following the **Apply online from outside the UK** link in https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse takes you to a page where it states “To complete your application, you must make arrangements to provide your biometrics”.